# Nested JSON to Core Data and ObjectForKey Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, core-data

I have 2 questions: 
I need to get the "Elements" & "Categori" from the JSON below, into my core data persistent store/database, I have tried the following (code below), but I am stuck and confused about if I am doing it the right way?

And I also get an error when I try to get the elements array with nested objectForKey, why and how can I fix it?

The error, which I don't understand since Elements is an array?

```
   reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd2f4a0'
```

I receive the JSON with AFNetworking like so:

```
         [[MyAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:domain parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

//IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY TO PROCESS NESTED JSON DATA IN CORE DATA? 

            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON options:0 error:&error];

            NSArray *arrayOfCategoriDictionaries = (NSArray *)[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Manifacture"] objectForKey:@"Categori"];


        //Categori array to Core data
            for( NSDictionary *d  in arrayOfCategoriDictionaries) {
               Categori *cat = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categori" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];


            }

    //Elements to core data, get an error with objectForKey:@"Elements" ?         

            NSArray *arrayOfElementsDictionaries = [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Manifacture"] objectForKey:@"Categori"] objectForKey:@"Elements"];



            for(NSDictionary *d1 in arrayOfRetDictionaries) {
                Elements *elements = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

            }






        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


            if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }





        }];
```

The nested json data:

```
   {
  "Manifacture": {
    "Categori": [
      {
        "Elements": [
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Door",
            "Description": "Black door with window",
            "Price": 149,
            "CategoriId": 1
          }
        ],
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Forret",
        "ElementsId": 1,
        "Manifacture_Id": 1
      }
    ],
    "CarSet": [],
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Hummer",
    "Description": "A big car"
  },
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Hummer Car Factory",
  "Contactperson": "Adil Bujas",
  "Location": "California",
  "Info": "Hummer LTD",
  "SearchThumbnail": "none",
  "CarPicture": "none",
  "Doors": 5,
  "webpages_MembershipUserId": 4,
  "Manifacture_Id": 1
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Please explain the vote down?

Comment: How many times is this question going to be asked over and over? Why don't people just darn look at the structure of their goddamn JSON and/or google the error message?

Comment: I have, but since I am a beginner, I dont have the overall understanding of the language yet and how it relates to my JSON, I just wanted to ask somebody who have this knowledge. And since it have been asked many times before, it seems to be really relevant. Just ignore the question, if you don't like it or share your knowledge, instead of writing such a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the case with `NSJSONSerialization`. I have seen certain JSON classes return arrays where only **1** object is in, as that object itself.

It is supposed to make it easier on you, but it ussually makes it harder on you, because you expect an NSArray with 1 object, but instead you get a NSDictionary of the first object of the array.

What happens if you do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Manifacture"] objectForKey:@"Categori"] objectForKey:@"Elements"] class]);
```

EDIT:

Ah, if you take a better look at your JSON, you will notice that the key `Categori` also contains an NSArray, but you are treating it like it contains a dictionary. That's probably where your error occurs.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for you answer. I get the same error: reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd2f4a0' if I run that NSLog

Comment: Updated my answer a bit, there's another sneaky array in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the cast and splitting up the statement to isolate any issue:

```
NSDictionary *manifactureDict = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Manifacture"];
NSArray *arrayOfCategoriDictionaries = [manifactureDict objectForKey:@"Categori"];
```

Or perhaps try casting the inner object to a dictionary:

```
NSArray *arrayOfCategoriDictionaries = [(NSDictionary*)[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Manifacture"] objectForKey:@"Categori"];
```

Comment: Casting doesn't change anything. Objective-C is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON options:0 error:&error];

        NSDictionary *theDict = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Manifacture"];

            NSArray *categoriArray = [theDict objectForKey:@"Categori"];

            for (NSDictionary *aDictionary in categoriArray) {
            NSDictionary *arrayOfElementsDictionaries = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"Elements"];

    }
```

Thank you for the help anyway.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is checked :)